# Как в Dapper.Plus сделать IGNORE поле при вставке?

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

У меня в таблице есть уникальное поле. Данных очень много по этому я добавляю их через Dapper.Plus `db.BulkInsert()` так как он быстрее всего их добавляет. Но в данных встречаются одинаковые поля, в SQL можно написать `INSERT IGNORE` и тогда поле с повтором просто не добавится.
Можно ли в Dapper.Plus сделать нечто подобное? Что бы при вставке поле с повтором просто его пропускало.